# How to create a texture with alpha in QOpenGLTexture？

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es-2.0, qtopengl

I'm trying to generate a texture with `QImage` and `QOpenGLTexture`.
I've set the `QImage` color format to `RGBA8888`, and set color with `setPixel`, but it seems like no matter how I change the alpha value, it remains to 255, and the transparency of the picture will never change.

Here's my code:

```
QImage texPic(width, height, QImage::Format_RGBA8888);
texPic.setPixel(0, 0, qRgba(255,0,0,0));
texPic.setPixel(0, 1, qRgba(0,255,0,100));
QOpenGLTexture *texture = new QOpenGLTexture(texPic);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, and I've solve the problem, it seems like it's the gl functions setting problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the problem, it's not from the setting of texture itself.
It because I didn't get the gl functions setting right.
I added

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
```

And now it worked.